# jwt - Django-rest-framework-jwt authentication in microsevices

Tags: jwt, microservices

I am newbie in JSON web token and micro services. I read in an articles that if i share the private, all services can verify user on their own. Then i tried to implement an application to practice.
Basically, I have two services A and B. A is used for authentication. Then, I tried implement a API that required authentication in service B. But when I used a token generated by authentication A in API, 401 status code and "Invalid signature." were returned. 
So anyone can explain to me what I did wrong?

Comment: "Invalid signature." means the token has been altered or you are using a bad key to verify. But it is impossible to say if you do not show the code where you generate and verify the JWT

Comment: i followed a tut here: http://polyglot.ninja/django-rest-framework-json-web-tokens-jwt/

Comment: just get a token, then try to use it with a protected api in another service using same secret key

Answer (score 1):

"Invalid signature" implies that the secret key that you used to encode the token doesn't match with the secret key you used for decoding it.

Make sure that the secret you are using for encoding and decoding are same.

For more info visit the [JWT's site](https://jwt.io/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all the service to service communication only need public key to be shared in case of an asymmetric key pair such as RSA or ECDSA. The public key shared can be used to verify the signature and each service needs to sign JWT using their private key. You have to take care of securing the private key and make public key accessible to other services.

Verifying the user is a completely different use case. The user existence should be checked in database and a password check can be made which is authentication is all about. The JWT can be used to pass the user information along with access right with a signature done by the application using private key so that no one able to generate the same token. NOTICE : Signature is done using private key. In this way you have both authentication and authorisation using JWT.